# Mysql concat select and update

Tags: mysql

I have two queries:

```
1) $query = "SELECT `login`, `password` FROM `TEST_ACCS` WHERE `sold` = '0' LIMIT 3";
```

And then I need change sold to 1 from the result of first query

```
2) $setQuery = "UPDATE `chrome_ext`.`TEST_ACCS` SET `sold` = '1' WHERE `sold` = '0' LIMIT 3";
```

How to concat these two queries into one?

I tried

```
UPDATE `chrome_ext`.`TEST_ACCS` dest, (SELECT `login`, `password` FROM `TEST_ACCS` WHERE `sold` = '0' LIMIT 3) src SET dest.sold = '1' where dest.sold= '0'
```

But it set sold = 1 to all raws, but need just 3

Comment: read about update and join

Comment: The result of the first query is a list of logins and passwords. How do you plan on getting the amount of sold products from that?

Comment: You can't `SELECT` and `UPDATE` in a single operation.  If you need to ensure they're performed atomically, execute them within a transaction.

Comment: You can use a limit clause in an update as well, but you cannot combine the 2 queries in such way into a single query that would return the username and password of those accounts, those sold field has been updated.